# How to intergrate mediawiki and jomsocial point system

Tags: joomla, mediawiki

i have a mediawiki and jomsocial challenge.   My goal is to encourage knowledge transfer in the work place by putting the JomSocial points system to use.  I want a way to have mediawiki send a notice to jomsocial to increase points value when ever someone saves a new page and/or edit. 5 points for new page, 1 or 2 points for edit.

So I would like to ask for some help finding information on how to make a hook in mediawiki that executes upon successful editing of a page.  Also, would it be possible to tell the difference between new and edit?

the second half of challenge is where to send the information to record the user action.  if anything, i was thinking about making a php page that increases the value in the database...so a hack of sort.  if i could fold it into existing jomsocial or joomla framework, that would be better =)

I know this is a tall order.  If anyone could just help point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replied to [a similar question regarding hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805770/how-to-trigger-a-signal-hook-on-edit-of-a-specific-page/9882095#9882095) recently. Take a look, should give you the basics.

IIRC, you can distinguish new page creations by using the `$flags` parameter of `ArticleSaveComplete`.

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about jomsocial so can't help you there.

Bonus: we (Wikia) have an [Achievements extension](http://trac.wikia-code.com/log/wikia/trunk/extensions/wikia/AchievementsII) that is a point-based reputation/gamification system that you might want to look to for, if nothing else, inspiration on what to reward.

Comment: Thanks this really pointed me in the right direction.  I've figured out how to do things on the jomsocial side.  this was the last piece.