# How to trigger a signal / hook on edit of a specific page?

Tags: rss, hook, signals, mediawiki

Is it possible to trigger some kind of signal or configure a hook (e.g. execution of defined / hard coded shell script) after editing one specific page of a MediaWiki?

The scenario is as follows.
Up to now a RSS feed is generated from the content of one specific MediaWiki page (call it `wiki/index.php?title=News`) each time the RSS feed is requested. As this page gets edited only once in a couple of days, having a Perl::CGI oder PHP script as the source of the RSS feed (e.g. URL for feed readers: `example.com/rss-feed.php`) should be better - in terms of server load. This script generates a static RSS feed (e.g. at `example.com/rss.xml`) only when the wiki page got edited.

*Remark:*
The wiki page I'm talking about is protected and only trusted users can edit it. I can not think about a security issue within the proposed workflow above. I'm happy getting otherwise convinced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, entirely possible.

The [ArticleSaveComplete hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ArticleSaveComplete)'s `$article` parameter contains the title and namespace of the article that's just been saved (specifically, you want to access the properties of `$article->mTitle`).

Simply define a function with an if statement that will just return `true` if the title (and namespace!) don't match the given data. If they do match, it will generate the static file you need.

The [MediaWiki Hooks manual page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks) has some examples and further info on how hooks work and how to go about writing a new function that will work with a specific hook.

That said, I would really advise you to consider dropping this idea, unless you're actually *seeing* adverse performance effects on your machine. Under a normal configuration, MediaWiki should use parser cache to take care of the most load-intensive operation for queries like this one.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. As you said, I'll drop that idea. The Perl script I mentioned above is pretty fast and does not cause a lot of load. I ended up using an hourly cron job running that script.